# Is there any way to use importOptions to import 10 jpeg files into jpeg sequence in AE extendscript?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

Is there any way to use `ImportOptions` to import 10 jpeg files into a jpeg sequence in AE extendscript?

my code:

```
 var path = "C:\\temp\\jpegSequence\\img001.jpg";

 var io = new ImportOptions(File(path));

 if (io.canImportAs(ImportAsType.FOOTAGE)){
     io.importAs = ImportAsType.FOOTAGE;
     io.sequence = true;
     io.forceAlphabetical = true;

     var sequence = app.project.importFile(io);    
     sequence.name = "blah";
 }
```

I have 10 images with ascending numbers in the same directory and I want them all in the same sequence.

thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to tell us what is _not_ working with your code.

Comment: thanks Patru, I found the solution and I placed posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

found an answer:

> To import multiple image files as a single still-image sequence, the files must be in the same folder and use the same numeric or alphabetic filename pattern (such as Seq1, Seq2, Seq3).

reference:
[Import a single still image or a still-image sequence](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/preparing-importing-still-images.html)

thanks